# LINQ - Map string arrays to list of objects

Tags: c#, .net, linq, linq-to-objects

How do I map string arrays to a list of objects?  A for loop would do it but wondering if there's a more elegant way to do this?  Perhaps with Linq?

String arrays:

```
string[] names = { "john","jane"};                                 
string[] companies = { "company ABC", "" };
string[] affiliations = { "affiliation 1", "affiliation 2" };
```

Contact:

```
public class Contact
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Company { get; set; }
    public string Affiliation { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string State { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I don't understand your question - what is it you wish to achieve?

Comment: One trusty for loop and an int index will do it :)

Comment: trying to find a more elegant solution than using a for loop.  Perhaps by using linq?

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you've ensured all of the arrays (*all of them*, not just the first three in your question) are exactly the same size and in the right order (so all the values will correspond to the right `Contact` objects), a for loop will suffice...

```
var contactList = new List<Contact>();

for (int i = 0; i < names.Length; i++)
{
    contactList.Add(new Contact
    {
        Name = names[i], 
        Company = companies[i], 
        Affiliation = affiliations[i],
        // etc
    });
}
```

Comment: You beat me to it. Deleting my answer since I like yours better.

Comment: yes a for loop would work but is there a more elegant solution?  linq?

Answer (score 1):

If you truly have both those definitions in your code, then you should just skip the string array step entirely.  Instead, initialize a list of `Contact` directly:

```
var contacts = new List<Contact>()
{
    new Contact()
    {
        Name = "john",
        Company = "company ABC",
        Affiliation = "affiliation 1",
    },
    new Contact()
    {
        // ...
    },
    // ...
};
```

This is more readable, and is less error prone, in case you have mis-matched list sizes, or don't have some data for one of the entries.